# Proof about number of vertices ($\mathbb{R}^3$ space)...

Tags: geometry

I do not fully understand the proof in Wikipedia, the first paragraph of [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedral_combinatorics#Equalities_and_inequalities).

$$
\begin{cases}
v − e + f = 2 \\
2e \ge 3f
\end{cases}
$$

Firstly $2e \ge 3f$ means that a facet has at least 3 edges, at the same time one edge exists besides exactly 2 facets - I guess that's how it is, right?

The conclusion $v \le 2f − 4$ however is still unclear. They simply took a legit $f \le 2v − 4$ and exchanged the variables. How is that allowed?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You left out the justification given for the resulting inequality: "by duality."

If you need help understanding what "by duality" means and why it gives the resulting inequality, see this link to [dual graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_graph). In particular, read the properties, and the summary:

> "Because of the duality, any result involving counting faces and vertices can be dualized by exchanging them." [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_graph]

Comment: I'd love to come up with the same property for $\mathbb{R}^4$. Do you think that's possible? Given that the above applies only to vertices-facets...

Comment: Over spaces, over 300 today! Nealy 30k :-))

Comment: @Babak: I've "capped" on upvote points (until 6 hours from now). I meant "accept" as in an accepted answer...there is no limit on points obtained from accepted answers.